# how to compare response from jsp page to ajax page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, jquery-ui, servlets

i am comparing the response i got from jsp page to ajax . i want to perform if out.print() print success message so i want to perform action in success ajax function . i am comparing data . but it is not working . i always go to else section . i am new in ajax . can please help me out with this problem.

```
      $.ajax({
    url: "login.jsp",
    //datatype: "text",
    type: "POST",

    data: datatopost,
    success: function(data){

        if(data.search("success")!=-1){ 
            console.log(data.data);
              $('#loginmessage').html(data);
              $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
            //show message
            $("#loginmessage").slideDown();
          //  window.location = "mainpageloggedin.jsp";
         //$('#loginmessage').text(data);  
        }else{
       // $('#loginmessage').text(data);   
            //hide spinner
            //window.location = "mainpageloggedin.jsp";
            $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
            //show message
            $("#loginmessage").slideDown();
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        $("#loginmessage").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax 
    Call. Please try again later.</div>");
        //hide spinner
        $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
        //show message
        $("#loginmessage").slideDown();

    }

});
```

jsp code...

```
 <%@ include file="connection.jsp"%>
 <%
 String email=request.getParameter("loginemail");
 String loginpass=request.getParameter("loginpassword");
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select password from users where email='"+email+"'");
 if(rs.next())
 {
 String password1=rs.getString(1);
 if(password1.equals(loginpass))
  {
    session.setAttribute("email",email);
    out.print("success");

   }
    else
  {
    out.print("invalid combination of email and password");
    }
 } else
     {out.print("this account does not have information");
   }

   %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's related to the `.search()` or the type of data that is being returned.

First, always review console and network to see what data package is being sent and received for AJAX. If you're not getting what's expected back, you may need to look at your Java.

If you're getting whats expected, consider the following code.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "login.jsp",
  datatype: "text html",
  type: "POST",
  data: datatopost,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data.search("success") > -1){ 
      console.log("Found 'success' in AJAX Package.");
      $('#loginmessage').html(data);
      $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
      //show message
      $("#loginmessage").slideDown();  
    } else {
      $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
      //show message
      $('#loginmessage').html("Login Failed. " + data);
      $("#loginmessage").slideDown();
    }
  },
  error: function(x, stat, err){
    $("#loginmessage").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax. Please try again later. (" + stat +", " + err + ")</div>");
    //hide spinner
    $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
    //show message
    $("#loginmessage").slideDown();
  }
});
```

In most cases, the AJAX will not `error` unless there is an error with the Web Server, so a 401, 404, or 500 error. So we want to make sure we're doing most of the work in in `success`, which is triggered when we get a 200 status.

So some text package is coming back. Based on your Java, this could be `success`, `invalid combination of email and password`, or `this account does not have information`. We can see what that package is upfront with console now. We then need to test it.

Since this is for AJAX, there is no way to test it for me. It's often best to use the simplest logical test. So `!= -1`will work, yet `> -1` is just as good and less confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try something like this

```js
function crudPost(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
    let email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    let parameters = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'process.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText)//get response from ur jsp
            
     // do stuff
        }

        let parameters = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email; //pass values when send
    }
    xhr.send(parameters)
    form.reset();
}
```

I just dont understand the problem u r facing in the code but try in this format it might help

Comment: i am camparing response in ajax page  which is comming from jsp  page . in ajax data.search("success") it is not executing . what is wrong in this .